# The boundaries of the figure I drawn are missing? How do I define a border for the tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following `tikz` code produces the figure attached below. The boundaries of the circles are missing. How do I include them in the figure?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Define the coordinates of the pentagon vertices
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (4,2.7);
  \coordinate (D) at (-1,2.7);
  \coordinate (E) at (1.5,4.0);

  % Draw the pentagon
  \draw[fill=yellow!70, opacity=0.8]  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (E) -- (D) -- cycle;
  \draw (A) -- (C);
  \draw (A) -- (E);
  \draw (B) -- (E);
  \draw (B) -- (D);

  \foreach \coord in {A,B,C,D, E}
    \draw[fill=blue!40,draw=black] (\coord) circle[radius=0.5];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}`, change `2mm` to whatever you prefer

Comment: This is a viewer issue, for me [the circles touch the boundary perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr1A3.png).

Answer (score 1):

Going to answer so the question can have one. The document class [`standalone`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) automatically reduces the border to `0pt` (p. 6, section 4.2 of the documentation), which in most cases doesn't present an issue. I suspect that if you zoomed in extremely closely to your circle borders then they would be present but that is dependent upon the software through which you view it.

The solution to your image therefore is the pass a value of your choosing to the optional class option `border=`, such as `1mm` etc:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Define the coordinates of the pentagon vertices
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (4,2.7);
  \coordinate (D) at (-1,2.7);
  \coordinate (E) at (1.5,4.0);

  % Draw the pentagon
  \draw[fill=yellow!70, opacity=0.8]  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (E) -- (D) -- cycle;
  \draw (A) -- (C);
  \draw (A) -- (E);
  \draw (B) -- (E);
  \draw (B) -- (D);

  \foreach \coord in {A,B,C,D, E}
    \draw[fill=blue!40,draw=black] (\coord) circle[radius=0.5];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]